# Google Spreadsheet Script: "Cannot find function getRange in object Sheet" when creating a simple function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sorry, for the stupid question, but I´ve searched the whole internet and I could not find a good Tutorial to learn how to program in Google SpreadSheet Script.

I want to make a very simple function just for practice.

```
function simplesum(input) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets();
  var range = sheet.getRange(input);

var x = 0;

for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {

var cell = range.getCell(i, j);

x += (cell.getValue());
}
}

return x;
}
```

I know I could use =sum() to do exactly the same thing. The idea here is to learn how to program.

When I try to use my function in a cell: (i.e: =simplesum((A1:A8)) it gives an Error saying: "TypeError: Cannot find function getRange in object Sheet. (line 4)"

What should I do?

And again, sorry for the dumb question....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you are implementing a Google Apps Script function as a *custom function*, invoked in a spreadsheet cell.

When you pass a range to a custom function invoked in a spreadsheet cell, you are not passing a range object or a range reference, but rather a 2-D Javascript array of values. So your custom function should just process that array.

```
function simplesum(input)
{
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
  {
    for (var j = 0; j < input[0].length; j++)
    {
      x += input[i][j];
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly!

Just one more stupid question: I´m used to programming on VBA. On Excel we can call a function, such as application.sum., from inside the code. Is there a way of doing this on Google Apps Script?

Comment: Spreadsheet functions are not available from google apps script.

Answer (score 4):

This is working :

```
function sum(input) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); // your mistake : getSheets() 
  var range = sheet.getRange(input);

  var x = 0;

  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {

     var cell = range.getCell(i, j);

      x += cell.getValue();
   }
 }

  return x;
}

function main () // Yes, I am a former C-programmer ...
{
   var s = sum ("A1:B3"); // Notice the quotes. A string must me entered here.
   Logger.log('s = ' + s);
}
```

Comment: Please add more details in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
var sheet = ss.getSheets();
```

returns an Array of sheets, meaning sheets.getRange(input) will throw that error.  Try this instead:

```
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
```

which selects the first sheet of the array of sheets.  Google has some decent documentation for this.  For example, [here's its documentation on getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange%28String%29).  Note that it uses ss.getSheets()[0] as well.  Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for you answer... I´ve made the adjustment, but now there is a new error: "Range not found (line 4)."

Comment: That seems to be an issue with your input -- what inputs are you using to create that new error?  Make sure that they are valid.